# Redis connection based on latency

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm writing a nodejs webserver that will exist in multiple regions across the world.

When using redis on node is it possible to provide a list of all my redis servers and the client can connect to the one that's closest based on latency?

Comment: Take a look at this discussion, might be helpful: http://serverfault.com/questions/65784/is-there-any-dns-that-supports-geo-location-directional-dns

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that you're using Redis 3+?

If so, `CLUSTER NODES` is your friend.

For a horrible bash example, on a Redis server with Puppet's `facter` installed,

```
INITMASTER1ID=$(redis-cli -h $(facter ipaddress) -c CLUSTER NODES  | grep $(facter ipaddress) | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+')
NODEIDLIST=$(redis-cli -h $REDIS2 -c CLUSTER NODES  | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+')
```

http://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes

For some less horrible examples written in Node.JS, check the docs for https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-cluster.